# Where can I get the css for a facebook sign-in/log-in button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I am using RoR and I've used omniauth and created a facebook sign in link. I want to make the link a facebook button, those you see on websites that uses social logins.

Currently, I just have

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook",user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path %>
```

I've tried using `<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>` but it does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be helpful :

**css**

```
/* Shared */
.loginBtn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 13em;  - apply for fixed size */
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0 15px 0 46px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.loginBtn:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 100%;
}
.loginBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.loginBtn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}


/* Facebook */
.loginBtn--facebook {
  background-color: #4C69BA;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4C69BA, #3B55A0);
  /*font-family: "Helvetica neue", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;*/
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #354C8C;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:before {
  border-right: #364e92 1px solid;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/icon_facebook.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:hover,
.loginBtn--facebook:focus {
  background-color: #5B7BD5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#5B7BD5, #4864B1);
}
```

**html**

```
<button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">
  Sign in with Facebook
</button>
```

You can try on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/davidelrizzo/pen/vEYvyv).

So your rails link would be

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path, class: 'loginBtn loginBtn--facebook' %>
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/). There's a [Font Awesome Rails gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) that'll let you use the Facebook icon.

Add the gem to your `Gemfile` and `bundle` it.

If you're using plain css, add this to your `application.css` file:

```
/*
 *= require font-awesome
 */
```

If you prefer Sass, change your `application.css` file to `application.css.scss` and add the line:

```
@import 'font-awesome';
```

Then you can use the `fa_icon` helper method.

```
<%= link_to fa_icon('facebook', text: "Sign in with Facebook"), user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path %>
```